# Convert JSON ToList and Parse it to EF Model

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to convert the json file I have ToList in C# after read it and then pass it to my model and add it to db. Now, my question is: how I can do that?

Here is my Json:

```
    {
  "Course: 1": {
    "Name": "Fundamentals of Yoga",
    "Category": "Health &amp; Fitness",
    "Headline": "An all levels guide to your yoga practice.",
    "CreatedBy": "Carleen Rose",
    "ExternalImage": "https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/1854410_de8b.jpg",
    "Duration": "5 hours",
    "Description": {
      "What You'll Learn": [
        "You'll have a great understanding of the foundations of yoga and basic anatomy so you'll safely be able to practice yoga anywhere!",
        "You'll be comfortable practicing in a public class and confident enough to practice yoga at home."
      ],
      "Requirements": [
        "The desire to begin or deepen your yoga practice!",
        "A place to practice, preferably on a yoga mat."
      ],
      "Description": "<div>\n                    Description\n                </div>\n\n                <p>Imagine building a house with the roof first. Or growing a tree starting with it's branches. Crazy right?&nbsp; Yet that's how many people start their yoga practice, with the imagined \"finished product\" they're trying to achieve. Even for a practiced yogi this can result in not knowing what you're doing or getting hurt.&nbsp; So many classes are still taught \u201cpose first\u201d but this revolutionary class is designed foundation first.</p><p>This course will start your practice from it's foundation or roots. It uses anatomy and physics to build your poses in a healthy alignment for your body and optimize your practice. It also activates your deep core strength, heats up your body and transitions you through poses in a way that gets you more results in less time and makes transformation accessible on all levels.</p><p>Whether you're looking for beginner yoga or something more advanced, this course will help you take your yoga practice to the next level.</p><p>Ready to channel your inner-superhero and transform your yoga practice? Then I'll see you on the mat! Namaste!!</p><p><strong>This course includes:</strong></p><ul><li><p>Workshop style videos teaching the foundations of yoga asana and anatomy</p></li><li><p>Topics and philosophies not normally discussed in a yoga class</p></li><li><p>Variety of complete yoga flows for your home practice</p></li><li><p>Pose tutorials of fun and challenging yoga poses</p></li><li><p>Surprise bonus material!</p></li></ul>\n\n                \n                    <div class=\"audience\" data-purpose=\"course-audience\">\n                        <div class=\"audience__title\">\n                            Who is the target audience?\n                        </div>\n                        <ul class=\"\n                            \n                                <li>Anyone who wants to build a lifelong yoga practice and enjoy all the benefits of yoga.</li>\n                            \n                                <li>Any level yogi, especially if you're wanting to take your practice outside of the yoga studio.</li>\n                            \n                                <li>Beginner yogis who want to learn the basics of yoga and start out their yoga journey.</li>\n                            \n                                <li>Advanced yogis who want to expand their practice and take it to the next level.</li>\n                            \n                        </ul>"
    }
  },
  "Course: 2": {
    "Name": "Complete Forex Trading- At Price Action Tricks and Tips",
    "Category": "Business",
    "Headline": "Recognise Market Trend And Start Interday or long term trading without taking big risk and get huge profit",
    "CreatedBy": "Rizwan azim",
    "ExternalImage": "https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/2023746_5bba_2.jpg",
    "Duration": "1 hour",
    "Description": {
      "What You'll Learn": [
        "Become professional trader and can earn good profit in forex buisness"
      ],
      "Requirements": [
        "Just Have Pc and Internet Connection"
      ],
      "Description": "<div>\n                    Description\n                </div>\n\n                <p>ake this course now and learn from my Long Time experience.</p><p> Avoid the most common pitfalls that catch 90% of traders!</p><p>Everything I explain here at live Mt4 Chart step by step </p><p>by live examples</p><p>Recognise Market Trend And Start Interday or long term trading</p><p>without taking big risk and get huge profit from every Trade </p><p><br></p><p> All you need is an open mind and a passion to be successful!</p><p><br></p><p>you have unlimited lifetime access at no extra costs, </p><p>ever</p><p>all future additional lectures, bonuses, etc</p><p><br></p>\n\n                \n                    <div class=\"audience\" data-purpose=\"course-audience\">\n                        <div class=\"audience__title\">\n                            Who is the target audience?\n                        </div>\n                        <ul class=\"\n                            \n                                <li>Every business mind person who want to earn big profit in Short time</li>\n                            \n                        </ul>"
    }
  }
}
```

My Post Model Class:

```
[Table("Post")]

public partial class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "External Image")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string ExternalImage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Author")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }    

    [Display(Name = "Size")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Size { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int? Category_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Duration")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Duration { get; set; }


}
```

and here is my code :

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("/data.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                foreach (var item in array)
                {
                    var ii = item;
                }

            }
```

What I need to do simply:

1. Convert the Json data => Tolist()
2. Read it from foreach loop
3. Assign the Values to the model and save it to database.

Comment: Well, there's nothing about a database in your code example, which bit are you struggling with? Can you map the JSON to a real class rather than dynamic? I mean, your JSON isn't actually an array so you won't be able to for each over it.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me, Actually why i should mention db ? already i posted my model class and what i need is to read from foreach and pass to db .. Anyway i have no problem to create a new class and save the values there then assign them to my model .. but how i can read the json from foreach ? that what i have no idea how to do

Comment: I think, if you're struggling to save to a database then you should ask another question and use this question to ask about parsing the JSON. If you need to iterate over the JSON courses you should read it in as a dictionary of string to some concrete class that represents the course.

Comment: I think already i explained what i do really need to do .. Any way i tried your suggestion and created a class and when i tried to fetch data it says i should change Json to Json Array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest first to make some classes to model the JSON:

```
public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ExternalImage { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    [JsonProperty("What You'll Learn")]
    public List<string> WhatYoullLearn { get; set; }
    public List<string> Requirements { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string DescriptionHtml { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I would suggest deserialising into the class, as follows:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("/data.json");
var courses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Course>>(json);
foreach (var course in courses)
{
    var courseName = course.Key;
    var courseDetails = course.Value;
    // Do something with the data, e.g save it to your database
}
```

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Tutorial.ViewModel.js]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: It's works , i just removed the [ ] between the start and end .. thanks for helping me and i appreciate that

Comment: @Dummies EBooks Good. I tested with the JSON you provided in the question and it worked for me so not sure which `[]` you needed to remove, but I'm glad it worked anyway.